# Capturing session after login

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to extract data from European DataWarehouse. After login it has one more form to fill. When I submit that form it returns blank list. It seems to be issue of capturing html_session after login. I can see the input fields of the form but it does not return desired output after I submit.

```
library(rvest)
url<-"https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edweb"
page<-html_session(url)
form <- html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(form,
                          UserName = "xxxx",
                          Password = "xxxx")

filled_form$url <- ""
session <- submit_form(page, filled_form)

link <- "https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edweb/Home/AdvancedSearch"
page2 <- html_session(link)
form2 <- session %>% jump_to(link) %>% html_form()
filled_form2 <- set_values(form2[[1]],
                          PostedAssetClassList.ItemIDs = "CMR",
                          PostedCountryOfSecuritizedAssetList = "Germany")
filled_form2$url <- link
session2 <- submit_form(page2, filled_form2, submit = "ButtonAction")
httr::content(session2$response)
```

Comment: Try taking out `page2 <- html_session(link)` once you create a session and login, you should not create another session.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting text using html_text() which shows account has not been loggedin.  It is unable to recognise account was already loggedin